# Laravel PHP validation Vs. Javascript validation

Tags: javascript, php, validation, laravel-5

I am implementing complete and detailed validation on server side using PHP Laravel. It is suggested that client side validation should be used for better user experience. How far should I go on front side? Should I duplicate every rule in client side? Or only HTML5 basic form validation is sufficient?

Comment: It depends on your requirement, you cant  make client side validation only if you are making payment gateway .

Comment: I would suggest at least using PHP validation so no manual made request would break your code, but saying that, going with client validation may or may not help the user experience. Usually it means more code to download, but less later server communication (if considering errors made).

Answer (score 2):

I add Javascript validation for the user experience. I always add backend validation so that when users turn off javascript or if another process tries to post to the backend directly validation is done on the backend.

Comment: Real question is "how far to go for client side validation if server side validation is complete", How much is sufficient and justified?

Comment: Whatever will provide the user with a solid and enriching user experience. It will be different for each form. For example, there are certain items that I will not validate in the JS, but will validate everything on the backend.

Answer (score 2):

client side validation are always executed on browser and will prevent you from submitting the invalid data from browser- the user experience becomes better because it takes short time to validate, You can use both JS or HTML5(works on all condition), but sometime people make it possible to submit data by removing required by inspecting and editing the element.

Now, server side validation is also mandatory because we should not allow invalid data.

Finally, HTML5 is enough for client side validation

Answer (score 1):

You can use server side validation on client side:

```
          $('body').on('submit', '#myform', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var $form = $(this);        

             $.ajax({
                type: $form.attr('method'),
                url: $form.attr('action'),
                data: $form.serialize(),
                success: function (data) {
                    //action
                },

                error: function(data){
                    $( "#myform input[type='text']" ).next().text( '' );
                    var errors = data.responseJSON;
                    $.each( errors, function( key, value ) {
                      $( "input[name='"+key+"']" ).next().text( value[0] );
                    });
                    }
            });

            return false;
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

### Pros of client-side validation

- "Better" user experience in the form of instant feedback to their input.
- Prevents HTTP requests that would otherwise result in an error.

### Cons of client-side validation

- Makes your codebase less [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself).
- Costs time and money.

---

The extent of your client-side validation depends on your business goals. Since you've got your server-side validation completed, the only technical advantage for client-side validation is saving HTTP requests (which may not matter depending on your traffic, hosting, etc).

I'd opt to start with no client-side validation and make sure the server-side errors show up correctly on submission failures. If you do that and you haven't reached the level of user experience you and your audience are expecting, then add HTML5 validation or better from there.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your requirement, you can only use Client Side validation using JS. But in that case there are chances when user disable the JS than your validation are of no use.

So I am suggesting you to put client as well as server side validation, so that in case if client side validation fails for any reason then server side will handle the task of validating the data.

Answer (score 0):

It is suppose to be purely depends upon on the software requirements.

**Server Side Validation**

In the Laravel Validation, the input submitted by the user is being sent to the server and validated. After the validation process on the Server Side, the feedback is sent back to the client by a new dynamically generated web page. It is better to validate user input on Server Side because you can protect against the malicious users, who can easily bypass your Client Side scripting language and submit dangerous input to the server.

**Client Side Validation**

In the Client Side Validation you can provide a better user experience by responding quickly at the browser level. When you perform a Client Side Validation, all the user inputs validated in the user's browser itself. Client Side validation does not require a round trip to the server, so the network traffic which will help your server perform better.

For example, if the user enter an invalid email format, you can show an error messeage immediately before the user move to the next field, so the user can correct every field before they submit the form.

**note for javascript validation:-** Mostly the Client Side Validation depends on the JavaScript Language, so if users turn JavaScript off, it can easilly bypass and submit dangerous input to the server . So the Client Side Validation can not protect your application from malicious attacks on your server resources and databases.

**note for php laravel validation:-** Necessary traffic to server and slower processing.

**Conclusion:-** As both the validation methods have their own significances, it is recommended that the **Server side validation is more SECURE!**